# Not getting any error log in Windows PowerShell while installing MSU

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-server-2019

While I am trying to install MSU manually in the windows 2019 server, I am getting one error like
"The update is not applicable to your computer". Because some alternative  KB has been installed already. So it's not allowed to install the MSU that I want to install. It's fine.

But when I am trying to install the same MSU through PowerShell by below mentioned PowerShell commend I am not getting any error log. I need a script to show the error log; if its any error. It has to skip this MSU installation. Experts please help me one this. I am looking forward to hear from you.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:SystemRoot\System32\wusa.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\MicrosoftEdge_KB\windows10.0-kb4520062-x64.msu /quiet /norestart" -Wait
```

Comment: Try to append `/Log:C:\MicrosoftEdge_KB\wusa.log`. Also you have duplicate backslash in `"C:\\MicrosoftEdge_KB` which should be removed.

Comment: @zett42  Hi Zett42, Thanks for the reply. I have followed the things which you have suggested. But log is in different format with only special characters, which is not able to understand.